# Am I too 'clever' to be readable by Jr. devs? Too much functional programming in my JS?

Tags: coding-style, functional-programming, teamwork, senior-developer, leadership

I'm a Sr. front-end dev, coding in Babel ES6.  Part of our app makes an API call, and based on the data model we get back from the API call, certain forms need to be filled out.

Those forms are stored in a doubly-linked list (if the back-end says some of the data is invalid, we can quickly get the user back to the one page they messed up and then get them back on target, simply by modifying the list.)

Anyway, there's a bunch of functions used to add pages, and I'm wondering if I'm being too clever.  This is just a basic overview - the actual algorithm is much more complex, with tons of different pages and page types, but this'll give you an example.

This is how, I think, a novice programmer would handle it.

```js
export const addPages = (apiData) => {
   let pagesList = new PagesList(); 

   if(apiData.pages.foo){
     pagesList.add('foo', apiData.pages.foo){
   }

   if (apiData.pages.arrayOfBars){
      let bars = apiData.pages.arrayOfBars;
      bars.forEach((bar) => {
         pagesList.add(bar.name, bar.data);
      })
   }

   if (apiData.pages.customBazes) {
      let bazes = apiData.pages.customBazes;
      bazes.forEach((baz) => {
         pagesList.add(customBazParser(baz)); 
      })
   } 

   return pagesList;
}
```

Now, in order to be more testable, I've taken all those if statements and made them separate, stand alone functions, and then I map over them.

Now, testable is one thing, but so is *readable* and I wonder if I'm making things less readable here.

```js
// file: '../util/functor.js'

export const Identity = (x) => ({
  value: x,
  map: (f) => Identity(f(x)),
})

// file 'addPages.js' 

import { Identity } from '../util/functor'; 

export const parseFoo = (data) => (list) => {
   list.add('foo', data); 
}

export const parseBar = (data) => (list) => {
   data.forEach((bar) => {
     list.add(bar.name, bar.data)
   }); 
   return list; 
} 

export const parseBaz = (data) => (list) => {
   data.forEach((baz) => {
      list.add(customBazParser(baz)); 
   })
   return list;
}


export const addPages = (apiData) => {
   let pagesList = new PagesList(); 
   let { foo, arrayOfBars: bars, customBazes: bazes } = apiData.pages; 

   let pages = Identity(pagesList); 

   return pages.map(foo ? parseFoo(foo) : x => x)
               .map(bars ? parseBar(bars) : x => x)
               .map(bazes ? parseBaz(bazes) : x => x)
               .value

}
```

Here's my concern.  To *me* the bottom is more organized.  The code itself is broken into smaller chunks that are testable in isolation.  BUT I'm thinking: If I had to read that as a junior developer, unused to such concepts as using Identity functors, currying, or ternary statements, would I be able to even understand what the latter solution is doing?  Is it better to do things the "wrong, easier" way sometimes?

Comment: Seems to me a bit of commenting would be fine. I agree it's more organized, but not at first glance as you need to jump up and down. If all those functions are in another module somewhere... It makes it that much less readable. But still highly organized in opinion.

Comment: as someone who only has 10 years self-teachings in JS, I would consider myself a Jr. and you lost me at `Babel ES6`

Comment: There's zero commenting or documentation of the above code :( even if you understand the newer syntax used it takes a minute to read all the pieces and assemble them together. Your problem isn't that you were too clever using functional programming, the problem is you never documented it

Comment: I am not convinced that your form is inherently easier to test. You are going to test addPages() itself (you wouldn't just assume the functions are composed correctly, right?), and an adequate test of that would adequately test your other functions. Furthermore, to test those sub-functions that return functions individually, you will have to set up a test harness for each, but you get that for free if you apply your test cases through addPages().

Comment: OMG - been active in industry since 1999 and coding since 1983, and you are the most harmful kind of developer there is. What you think is "clever" is really called "expensive" and "hard to maintain" and "a source of bugs" and it has no place in a business environment. The first example is simple, easy to understand *and it works* while the second example is complex, hard to understand, and not provably correct. Please stop doing this kind of thing. It is NOT better, except maybe in some academic sense that doesn't apply to the real world.

Comment: A little documentation and willingness to repeatedly explain yourself goes a long way. If you don't have the luxury of working closely with the jr devs then you may want some kind of commenting in there, or just go with the way most people will understand. I don't agree with the harshness of user1068 above because a jr dev needs to be able to learn shop practice. If they can't adapt, they'll never not be jr. However, "expensive" can be very true. To me both your examples are the same. They both require some explaining to a jr dev, so it's your choice how hard you want to make teaching them

Comment: I think your code looks excellent. Breaking stuff up in small bits makes the code only *seem* more complex. And that's actually a good thing. It will prevent juniors from messing with it before understanding it. Once that understanding is gained, I agree with you this code is a lot more maintainable because each function is so small it's almost immediately clear where to change something if the behavior needs changing. In my opinion code like this often ends up not needing many changes anyway!  ;)

Comment: I just want to quote Brian Kerninghan here: "Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?" - https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Brian_Kernighan / "The Elements of Programming Style", 2nd edition, chapter 2.

Comment: @user1068 the problem isn't that the code was refactored per se - the original code could use some refactoring; specifically there are good opportunities for abstraction/decomposition there that would make the code easier to understand, modify and extend... the problem is that the code was refactored very poorly and made not only harder to understand, modify and extend but also made considerably less efficient.

Comment: Screw the haters. I think your code is very cool. The problem isn't that it is difficult; complexity may be worth the gains in testability etc. The problem is that you could achieve the same gains with code that is simpler. Many answers/commenters seem to think that simplicity is the primary objective. They are wrong.

Comment: @Logister Coolness is no more a primary objective than simplicity. The objection here is to *gratuitous* complexity, which is the enemy of correctness (surely a primary concern) because it makes the code harder to reason about and more likely to contain unexpected corner cases. Given my earlier-stated skepticism of claims that it actually is easier to test, I have not seen any convincing argument for this style. In analogy with the rule of least privilege wrt security, perhaps there could be a rule of thumb that says one should be wary of using powerful language features to do simple things.

Comment: "It is not enough for your solution to be correct. It must be obviously correct."

Comment: @Logister What  gains in testability?

Comment: Your code looks like junior code. I would expect a senior to write the first example.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem - (1) I'm taking the author of at his word when he says that his construction improves testability. This is a simplified version of the real problem. Testability improvements may be non-obvious in the toy example. (2) You can write tests for the individual curried functions separately by passing in test lists/data and composing them in a variety of ways. That would not be the case in the "novice" version where you have to test all the sub-functions simultaneously.

Comment: @Logister Changes of the type shown here do _not_ improve testability.  Sure, maybe OP has made a whole lot of other changes too, and failed to show them  in this particular example.  But there's no point in talking about stuff that we can't see.  Moreover, if there are scenarios that _can_ exist for the second snippet but not the first, then they're clearly not scenarios that OP needs to model; in which case, it seems pointless to test them.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Consider the possibility that `customBazParser` and the like could be arbitrarily complex. Passing a data structure through a series of such processes could have unforeseen side-effects. Separating these sorts of things into different, individually testable functions is superior to having one test for one long, complicated series of loops and undifferentiated operations. Could it be done better? Yes (see b0nyb0y's answer). But even in the toy example testability is improved.

Comment: 2nd code is an example of teenager phase of programmer.

Answer (score 324):

In your code, you have made multiple changes:

- destructuring assignment to access fields in the `pages` is a good change.
- extracting the `parseFoo()` functions etc. is a possibly good change.
- introducing a functor is … very confusing.

One of the most confusing parts here is how you are mixing functional and imperative programming. With your functor you aren't really transforming data, you are using it to pass a *mutable list* through various functions. That doesn't seem like a very useful abstraction, we already have variables for that. The thing that should possibly have been abstracted – only parsing that item if it exists – is still there in your code explicitly, but now we have to think around the corner. For example, it's somewhat non-obvious that `parseFoo(foo)` will return a function. JavaScript doesn't have a static type system to notify you whether this is legal, so such code is really error prone without a better name (`makeFooParser(foo)`?).  I don't see any benefit in this obfuscation.

What I'd expect to see instead:

```js
if (foo) parseFoo(pages, foo);
if (bars) parseBar(pages, bars);
if (bazes) parseBaz(pages, bazes);
return pages;
```

But that's not ideal either, because it is not clear from the call site that the items will be added to the pages list. If instead the parsing functions are pure and return a (possibly empty) list that we can explicitly add to the pages, that might be better:

```js
pages.addAll(parseFoo(foo));
pages.addAll(parseBar(bars));
pages.addAll(parseBaz(bazes));
return pages;
```

Added benefit: the logic about what to do when the item is empty has now been moved into the individual parsing functions. If this is not appropriate, you can still introduce conditionals. The mutability of the `pages` list is now pulled together into a single function, instead of spreading it across multiple calls. Avoiding non-local mutations is a far bigger part of functional programming than abstractions with funny names like `Monad`.

So yes, your code was too clever. Please apply your cleverness not to write clever code, but to find clever ways to avoid the need for blatant cleverness. The best designs don't *look* fancy, but look obvious to anyone who sees them. And good abstractions are there to simplify programming, not to add extra layers that I have to untangle in my mind first (here, figuring out that the functor is equivalent to a variable, and can effectively be elided).

Please: if in doubt, keep your code simple and stupid (KISS principle).

Comment: From a symmetry point of view, what does `let pages = Identity(pagesList)` have different from `parseFoo(foo)`? Given that, I would probably have... `{Identity(pagesList), parseFoo(foo), parseBar(bar)}.flatMap(x -> x)`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that having three nested lambda expressions for collecting a mapped list (to my untrained eye) might be a bit _too_ clever.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60112/discussion-on-answer-by-amon-am-i-too-clever-to-be-readable-by-jr-devs-too-m).

Comment: Maybe a fluent style would work good in your second example?

Answer (score 227):

If you are in doubt, it probably is too clever! The second example introduces *accidental complexity* with expressions like `foo ? parseFoo(foo) : x => x`, and overall the code is more complex which means it is harder to follow.

The purported benefit, that you can test the chunks individually, could be achieved in a simpler way by just breaking into individual functions. And in the second example you couple the otherwise separate iterations, so you actually get *less* isolation.

Whatever your feelings about functional style in general, this is clearly an example where it makes the code more complex.

I find a bit of a warning signal in that you associate simple and straightforward code with "novice developers". This is a dangerous mentality. In my experience it is the opposite: Novice developers are prone to overly complex and clever code, because it requires more experience to be able to see the simplest and clearest solution.

The advice against "clever code" is not really about whether or not the code uses advanced concepts which a novice might not understand. Rather it is about writing code which is *more complex or convoluted than necessary*. This makes the code harder to follow for *everybody*, novices and experts alike, and probably also for yourself some months down the line.

Comment: "Novice developers are prone to overly complex and clever code, because it requires a more experience to be able to see the simplest and clearest solution" can't agree more with you. Excelent answer!

Comment: Overly complex code is also quite passive-aggressive. You're deliberately producing code that few others can read or debug easily...which means job security for you, and utter hell for everyone else in your absence. You may as well write your technical documentation entirely in Latin.

Comment: I don't think clever code is always a show off thing. Sometimes it feels natural, and only looks ridiculous on a second inspection.

Comment: In this case it was something like, "we had this nice simple functional approach, but then we needed to make it testable so just take some functions from here and put them there..."

Comment: I have removed the phrasing about "showing off" since it sounded more judgmental than intended.

Comment: @BaileyS - I think that emphasises the importance of code review; what feels natural and straightforward to the coder, especially when gradually developed that way, can easily seem convoluted to a reviewer. The code then doesn't pass review until refactored / rewritten to remove the convolution.

Comment: @johnny here and I thought the guy that did that was just trying to make his comments be harry potter spells! Who knew he was a sociopath and not just a nerd!

Answer (score 23):

This answer of mine comes a bit late, but I still want to chime in. Just because you're using the latest ES6 techniques or using the most popular programming paradigm doesn't necessarily mean that your code is more correct, or that junior's code is wrong. Functional Programming (or any other technique) should be used when it's actually needed. If you try to find the tiniest chance to cram latest programming techniques into every problem, you will always end up with an over-engineered solution.

Take a step back, and try to verbalize the problem you're trying to solve for a second. In essence, you just want a function `addPages` to transform different parts of `apiData` into a set of key-value pairs, then add all of them into `PagesList`.

And if that's all there is to it, why bother using `identity function` with `ternary operator`, or using `functor` for input parsing? Besides, why do you even think it's a proper approach to apply `functional programming` that causes [side-effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29) (by mutating the list)? Why all those things, when all you need is just this:

```js
const processFooPages = (foo) => foo ? [['foo', foo]] : [];
const processBarPages = (bar) => bar ? bar.map(page => [page.name, page.data]) : [];
const processBazPages = (baz) => baz ? baz.map(page => [page.id, page.content]) : [];

const addPages = (apiData) => {
  const list = new PagesList();
  const pages = [].concat(
    processFooPages(apiData.pages.foo),
    processBarPages(apiData.pages.arrayOfBars),
    processBazPages(apiData.pages.customBazes)
  );
  pages.forEach(([pageName, pageContent]) => list.addPage(pageName, pageContent));

  return list;
}
```

(a runnable jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b0nyb0y/L96c06e6/))

As you can see, this approach still uses `functional programming`, but in moderation. Also note that since all 3 transformation functions cause no side effects whatsoever, they are dead easy to test. The code in `addPages` is also trivial and unassuming that novices or experts can understand by just a mere glance.

Now, compare this code with what you've come up with above, do you see the difference? Undoubtedly, `functional programming` and ES6 syntaxes are powerful, but if you slice the problem the wrong way with these techniques, you'll end up with even messier code.

If you don't rush into the problem, and applying the right techniques in the right places, you can have the code that is functional in-nature, while still is very organized and maintainable by all team members. These characteristics are not mutually-exclusive.

Comment: +1 for pointing out this wide-spread attitude (does not necessarily apply to the OP): "Just because you're using the latest ES6 techniques or using the most popular programming paradigm doesn't necessarily mean that your code is more correct, or that junior's code is wrong.".

Comment: +1. Just a small pedantic remark, you can use the spread (...) operator instead of _.concat to remove that dependency.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Ah, good catch. Now you know that me and my team are still on the journey of unlearning some of our `lodash` use. That code can use `spread operator`, or even `[].concat()` if one wants to keep the shape of the code intact.

Comment: Sorry, but this code listing is still much less obvious to me than the original "junior code" in OP's post. Basically: Never use ternary operator if you can avoid it. It's too tense. In a "real" functional language, if-statements would be expressions and not statements, and therefore more readable.

Comment: @OlleHärstedt Umm, that's an interesting claim you made. The thing is, Functional Programming paradigm, or any paradigm out there, is never tied down to any particular "real" functional language, much less its syntax. Thus, dictating what conditional constructs should be or should "never" be used just doesn't make any sense. A `ternary operator` is as valid as a regular `if` statement, whether you like it or not.

The readability debate between `if-else` and `?:` camp is never-ending, so I won't get into it. All I will say is, with trained eyes, lines like these are hardly "too tense".

Comment: @OlleHärstedt `?:` is just a different spelling of "expression `if else`" because those names were already taken

Answer (score 6):

The second snippet is *not* more testable than the first.  It would be reasonably straightforward to set up all the needed tests for either one of the two snippets.

The real difference between the two snippets is comprehensibility.  I can read the first snippet fairly quickly and understand what's  going on.  The second snippet, not so much.  It's far less intuitive, as well as substantially longer.

That makes the first snippet easier to maintain, which is a valuable quality of code.  I find very little of value in the second snippet.

Answer (score 3):

**TD;DR**

1. Can you explain your code to the Junior Developer in 10 minutes or less?
2. Two months from now, can you understand your code?

**Detailed Analysis**

**Clarity and Readability**

The original code is impressively clear and easy to understand for any level of programmer.  It is in a style *familiar to everybody*.

*Readability is largely based on familiarity, not some mathematical counting of tokens*.  IMO, at this stage in time, you have too much ES6 in your rewrite.  Maybe in a couple of years I'll change this part of my answer. :-)  BTW, I also like the @b0nyb0y answer as a reasonable and clear compromise.

**Testability**

```
if(apiData.pages.foo){
   pagesList.add('foo', apiData.pages.foo){
}
```

Assuming that PagesList.add() has tests, which it should, this is completely straightforward code and there is no obvious reason for this section to need special separate testing.

```
if (apiData.pages.arrayOfBars){
      let bars = apiData.pages.arrayOfBars;
      bars.forEach((bar) => {
         pagesList.add(bar.name, bar.data);
      })
   }
```

Again, I see no immediate need for any special separate testing of this section.  Unless PagesList.add() has unusual issues with nulls or duplicates or other inputs.

```
if (apiData.pages.customBazes) {
      let bazes = apiData.pages.customBazes;
      bazes.forEach((baz) => {
         pagesList.add(customBazParser(baz)); 
      })
   }
```

This code is also very straightforward.  Assuming that `customBazParser` is tested and doesn't return too many "special" results.  So again, unless there are tricky situations with `PagesList.add(), (which there could be as I'm not familiar with your domain) I don't see why this section needs special testing.

In general, testing the whole function should work fine.

**Disclaimer**: If there are special reasons to test all 8 possibilities of the three `if()` statements, then yes, do split up the tests.  Or, if `PagesList.add()` is sensitive, yes, split up the tests.

**Structure: Is it worth breaking up into three parts (like Gaul)**

Here you have the best argument.  Personally, I don't think the original code is "too long" (I'm not a SRP fanatic).  But, if there were a few more `if (apiData.pages.blah)` sections, then SRP rears it's ugly head and it would be worth splitting.  Especially if DRY applies and the functions could be used in other places of the code.

**My one suggestion**

YMMV.  To save a line of code and some logic, I might combine the **if** and **let** into one line:  *e.g.*

```
let bars = apiData.pages.arrayOfBars || [];
bars.forEach((bar) => {
   pagesList.add(bar.name, bar.data);
})
```

This will fail if apiData.pages.arrayOfBars is a Number or String, but so will the original code.  And to me it is clearer (and an overused idiom).